# Is there any way to upload photos from my computer to ec2?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I would like to upload a photo from my computer to ec2, I know that you can use s3 and the boto3 library, but this does not suit me, since the photos themselves should be on ec2 (processed there), and downloading them using python with s3 takes too much  time (I want to upload and process photos on ec2, but downloading and uploading them to s3 takes extra time)

Example of what i want

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.upload_file(path_in_my_computer)
```

Comment: ...yes? There are many ways to do this, as EC2 just lets you have a virtual machine running on Amazon's infrastructure. What does "this does not suit me, since the photos themselves must be on ec2, and downloading them using python with s3 takes extra time" mean? How would retrieving a file from s3 take any more time than retrieving one from EC2? What is your use case where this would be relevant? Please read [ask]. This is far too broad and lacks clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect('... .compute.amazonaws.com', username='ubuntu', password='',
               key_filename='D:\key.pem')

# Setup sftp connection and transmit this script
print("copying")

sftp = client.open_sftp()
sftp.put('1.jpg', '/home/ubuntu/1.jpg')

sftp.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, you can use `scp`:

Example:

```
scp -i my_key.pem /Path/where/the/photo/is/located ec2-user@your-amazon-instance
```

[Transferring files to Linux instances from Linux using SCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

Comment: And how do I do this in python code. Can describe in more detail and provide a more detailed example?

Comment: SCP library for Python: https://pypi.org/project/scp/